# Why doesn't VS debugger stop at initialized variable?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I set a breakpoint in a variable which is not initialized and run the project, I observed that at run time the debugger doesn't stops at that line instead of it, it hits the immediate next line of the not initialized variable.

I also observed that at the run time breakpoint is also display on next line.

Example:

```
string strTest; // Set breakpoint here.
Console.WriteLine("This is test"); // The debugger stops here, not in the line above.
strTest = "Hi I am Test"; // Initialize string variable here.
```

Is this the expected behavior? I mean why VS debugger doesn't stops at not initialized variable? and also why at run time breakpoint moves to the next line of not initialized variable?

Comment: It's probably being optimized out

Comment: @OMGtechy There's no code *to* optimize out.  Declaring a variable does nothing in the compiled code, as mentioned in the answer.  Declaring variables before you use them is purely a construct of higher level languages.

Comment: Good thing in Visual Studio 2015 *(Preview)*, You can't set breakpoint at variable declaration.

Comment: @Servy, "Declaring a variable does nothing in the compiled code": that's not true; it reserves some space on the stack (you can see it in IL). But it's not a statement, so there's no executable code associated with it.

Answer (score 9):

Variable declarations don't produce code. As such, there's no code before which to break on that line.

Comment: Not sure why you came back to this discussion 3 years later and deleted all your comments... makes it look like I was talking to myself, so I deleted mine as well ;)